# Smartsheet API Attachement

Tags: vb.net, smartsheet-api

I am having a problem with the attachemnt in the smartsheet API.

It keeps telling me that the file path format is not supported at this line

```
smartSheet.SheetResources.RowResources.AttachmentResources.AttachFile(id, 1, "N:\TEST\M-TST-12346\M-TST-12346-TV.pdf", "application/pdf")
```

Any help would be awesome!

```
Public Sub GetSheetsInWorkspace(workspaceID As Int64)
        Dim workspace As Workspace
        workspace = smartSheet.WorkspaceResources.GetWorkspace(workspaceID, Nothing, Nothing)
        Dim folder As Folder
        folder = smartSheet.FolderResources.GetFolder(5398922303694724, Nothing)
        Dim sheets As List(Of Sheet)
        sheets = folder.Sheets
        For Each sheet In sheets
            If sheet.Name = "ALAN S. INPUT" Then
                Dim id
                id = sheet.Id
                smartSheet.SheetResources.RowResources.AttachmentResources.AttachFile(id, 1, "N:\TEST\M-TST-12346\M-TST-12346-TV.pdf", "application/pdf")
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to AttachFile is rowId, not row number. I believe your 'not found' error was due to the Row not being found
To get the id of the first row, you'll need to call  SheetResources.GetSheet() to get a collection of Row objects.

BTW, backslashes should *not* be escaped in VB string

Try code like this

```
mySheet = ss.SheetResources.GetSheet(sheetId, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
Dim rowId As Long
rowId = mySheet.Rows.First.Id
ss.SheetResources.RowResources.AttachmentResources.AttachFile(sheetId, rowId, "C:\tmp\test.pdf", "application/pdf")
```

Comment: That's exactly what I figured out. I thought I could get the rowId from the sheet in sheets, but that didn't hold and row value.
I instead had to grad the sheet from SheetResources, which held the row information.
Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it'd be helpful to compare what you're doing to the [integration test code](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-csharp-sdk/blob/master/IntegrationTestSDK/AttachmentResourcesTest.cs) that's available as part of the SDK? Specifically, the **AttachFileAndUrlToRow** method in the file I've linked to contains this line for adding an attachment to a row:

```
Attachment attachment = smartsheet.SheetResources.RowResources.AttachmentResources.AttachFile(sheetId, rowId, path, null);
```

...where the value of **path** is defined as follows:

`string path = "../../../IntegrationTestSDK/TestFile.txt";`

Comparing that test code to the code that you've posted, I notice a few differences:

- your code uses (single) backslashes (\) in the file path, whereas the SDK test code uses forward-slashes (/)
- you're specifying a path that uses a drive mapping (N:\), whereas the SDK test code specifies a relative path
- you're passing in a value for the last parameter (`application/pdf`), whereas the SDK test code specifies `null` for the last parameter.

Perhaps as a first step in troubleshooting, *escape* each of the backslashes in your file path-- i.e., add an extra backslash to each occurrence:

```
smartSheet.SheetResources.RowResources.AttachmentResources.AttachFile(id, 1, "N:\\TEST\\M-TST-12346\\M-TST-12346-TV.pdf", "application/pdf")
```

If that doesn't resolve your issue, then perhaps try changing each backslash to a forward-slash (consistent with what the SDK test code does):

```
smartSheet.SheetResources.RowResources.AttachmentResources.AttachFile(id, 1, "N:/TEST/M-TST-12346/M-TST-12346-TV.pdf", "application/pdf")
```

Additionally (although likely unrelated to your issue) -- looks like you're passing a value of `1` for **rowId**, which isn't correct -- **rowId** should be a GUID (for example, something more like this: `4583173393803140`).

Comment: Im starting to think its the rowID. If i change the path to a correct path, it likes it, but gives me an error "Not Found" now. Not the path... just "Not Found". I believe this has to do with the rowID.
Which I can grab... but it's telling me that the sheet has 0 rows, which I know it does. Going to dig some more. Thanks for your input! I will update later

Comment: Got it now. I had to open the SheetResources in order to get Row.ID.
Thanks for that!!